# Обработка VBI-данных в OSX

Tags: c++, macos, драйвер

**Окружение**: macOS, драйвер для оцифровки аналогового видео (кроме видео обрабатывается звук и [VBI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_blanking_interval) данные).

**Драйвер**: на уровне драйвера я имею доступ к потокам видео и VBI данных, которые представляют собой обыкновенные потоки байтов.

**Вопрос**: как в OSX создать стрим c VBI данными? В Linux-based операционных системах драйвер v4l2 создает устройство /dev/vbi, которое выступает в роли декодера, с которого мы и забираем декодированный телетекст. В macOS для создания видео потока, например, мы используем класс `IOVideoStream` - что можно использовать для создания потока с VBI данными? Может нужно обратить внимание не на kernel-space, а на user-space - посмотреть assistant и\или plugin?